# How to use lambda layer in tensorflow functional API for an arbitrary function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Suppose I have the input of form [a,b,c] and I want to produce the output [a * b, b * c]

I thus would try something like this:

```
input = Input((3,))
output = Lambda(lambda x: [x[0]*x[1], x[1]*x[2]], output_shape = (2,))(input) 
model = Model(input, output)
```

However, it seems to not work. When I print the summary I get:

```
shape(input) = (None,3)
shape(output) = [(3,),(3,)] ## shouldn't this be (None,2)?
```

Answer (score 1):

Input tensor `x` in your case has shape `(None,3)` so `x[0]` is first sample in batch and not a first feature. You should use `x[:,0]` instead. Also returing list of tensors from layers means that layers has multiple outputs (not single output with multiple features) so you will need to stack them with `tf.stack`.

Here is sample code:

```py
input = Input((3,))
output = Lambda(lambda x: tf.stack([x[:,0]*x[:,1], x[:,1]*x[:,2]], axis=1))(input)
```

Results

```py
input.shape # TensorShape([None, 3])
output.shape # TensorShape([None, 2])
```

Comment: Great answer. Would also add that you can golf the Lambda layer further by using a vectorized multiply: `output = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0:2]*x[:,1:3])(input)`